# Check broken link webservice

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, same-origin-policy

Due to the *same origin policy* I cannot request an external url by myself in javascript. So I'm looking for some rest webservice (that implements the allow-external-origin header) that can do the job for me:

Ex:

request:
http://foo.com?linkToCheck=www.google.it

response:
status = 200

Does it exist?

Comment: Maybe you can do this in your own backend and call that from javascript?

Comment: @Arg0n I Actually did it (and it works), but my teammates are unhappy because they believe it's a client field of action and i'm loading server with useless calls. So I'm looking for some external ws to query :)

Answer (score 0):

What about a refine something like:

```
function check(url, fn) {
    var i = document.createElement('iframe'),
        to = 5000,
        t,
        res = false;
    i.style.display = 'none';
    i.onload = function (){
        res = true;
        document.body.removeChild(i);
        clearTimeout(t);
        fn(true);
    };
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        !res && fn(false);
        document.body.removeChild(i);
    }, to);
    i.src=url;
    document.body.appendChild(i);
}

check('//www.googleDoesNotExists.com', function (r){
  alert(r);
});
check('//www.google.com', function (r){
  alert(r);
});
```